# Sync bucket to local directory without duplicates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am currently trying to download a massive (500Gb) bucket to my external hard drive.
I downloaded about 200Gb of it and then it timed out.
To do this I used

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket /Local/Folder --recursive
```

Now I want to keep the download going but I don't want any duplicates, just to download the remaining folders.

I tried using

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket /Local/Folder
```

But I don't think it worked properly because now I have currently downloaded 400Gb ADDITIONAL Gb – so 600 in total.

What command should I use and what did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I am using sync command which you mentioned, its working fine. I hope you are not making any changes in your local folder/file (i.e. creation/modification date)

Comment: Can you compare the contents of the bucket with the contents of the external drive to find the variation? Are the number of files different? How are you calculating the sizes in both locations?

Comment: Difficult to compare because its my company's bucket and its got > 500GB of data so not even totally sure where to look.

Getting the size with cmd ````df -h```` as well as finder's get info.  It's weird because it should only be a bucket of around 500 GB and I'm now at 800 GB of space used up on the external hard drive so I don't quite understand what's going on.  There still doesn't seem to be any duplicate folders being created at least (there are only 20 folders or so at the top level of the bucket).